# Check if 2nd word in every element of a list is of length 1 and remove that element from the list using Python

Tags: python

I have a list with three elements:
`cleaned_str = ['Washington C, Bright G, Gleider A', 'Mine C', 'This is not fun'].`
I want to remove those elements from the list where the 2nd word of each element in the list is of length 1.
Eg. 'Washington C, Bright G, Gleider A' - 2nd word 'C' after Washington is of length 1, so this element should be removed.
So, after processing, I will only get one item in this list = ['This is not fun'].
Your help is very much appreciated.

```
    str_to_clean = "Washington C, Bright G, Gleider A.Mine C.This is not fun."
    cleaned_str = []
    for sentence in str_to_clean.split("."):
         cleaned_str.append(sentence)
print("Output", ".".join(cleaned_str))
```

This gave me the list as output. I am trying to figure out how 're' can help me in identifying the 2nd word in each item of the list. If I use further split on it, how can I then join back to remove the entire item from that list? That is where I am stuck.

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself?

Comment: May I recommend https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Hint: Try thinking about building a new list from filtered elements in your existing list. As @kaya3 said, the `re` package should help with the filtering part. Attempt a solution and edit this question to show where you still need help

Comment: I would say to use `split()` with `for` loop to iterate over the list. `re` can be overwhelming for starting up.

Comment: In str_to_clean you are using a mixture of '.' and ',' as separators.  Is this intentional?

Comment: It is not about getting the names only. The names are in the 1st two items of the list. 1st item has 3 names, 2nd item has 1 name. So , basically, my idea is to identify the 2nd word having word length 1 looking from first word in each item and remove that entire item from the list.

Comment: In str_to_clean you are using a mixture of '.' and ',' as separators. Is this intentional? Answer is : Yes, Darryl

Comment: My raw data is string of the three sentences. I do have many more sentences, but this is a sample. I needed to split the data into three lines and then check line by line if it satisfies the condition: 2nd word is of word length 1. Basically I need to get rid of lines having names. I checked the names have a familiar pattern, i.e. name ending with a single letter. So trying to find that pattern for removal.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string at the '.' character, removing the last element, that was an empty string

*['Strömberg C, Johansson G, Adolfsson A', 'Mine C', 'This is not fun', '']*

After this you just have to run a loop over the list and not append in the condition that you mention "where the 2nd word of each element in the list is of length 1":

```
str_to_clean = "Strömberg C, Johansson G, Adolfsson A.Mine C.This is not fun."
str_to_clean = str_to_clean.split('.')[:-1]
cleaned_str = []

for sentence in str_to_clean:
    sentence = sentence.split(' ')
    if len(sentence[1].strip(',')) != 1:
        sentence = ' '.join(sentence)
        cleaned_str.append(sentence)

print(cleaned_str)
------------------------
['This is not fun']
```

Comment: Thanks @Luan. But then I still get the 1st item having 'C' which is also of word length 1. My objective is to check the 2nd word length in each item of the list and remove that item fully from the list.

Answer (score 1):

renamed the list to xlist to avoid using a reserved word

```
xlist = ['Washington C', 'Bright G', 'Gleider A', 'Mine C', 'This is not fun']

for x in xlist:
    if len(x.split()[1]) != 1:
        print (x)
```

returns

```
This is not fun
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list look like this:

```
list = ['Washington C', 'Bright G', 'Gleider A', 'Mine C', 'This is not fun']
```

You just need to run with loop over the list, split the strings and take the len of the second object, and thats all (assuming you do not want to study re now).

For deleting objects from lists, look at this https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove

Comment: Good suggestions, but bad practice to use names of commonly used built-in functions as variable names (i.e. **list** in this case) since it shadows the built-in function.  Why not just use the OP name i.e. str_to_clean?